# How to update all the 3 dropdownlist in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

so i was doing this cascading dropdownlist control to get state,when country dropdown is changed and similarly ,get city on state change..so i was getting whole page refreshed ..so i tried update panel but only state was getting populated on country change but i was not able to change city for some reason..in current code now on state change i have kept city change ,but i want all dropdown to work in update panel i.e on selection of country ,state should be populated and on selection of state ,city should be populated..i am attaching the code

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <div class="input-single  valid">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" TabIndex="13" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <small class="error">Country is required.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                <div id="countrySubdivisionDiv" class="input-single">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <small class="error">Region/State/Province is required.
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </ContentTemplate>                                                          
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <div class="input-single">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="fdf" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"   maxlength="50"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>                                                          
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <small class="error">City is required.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <div class="input-single">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server" placeholder="Post Code" MaxLength="15" TabIndex="16"></asp:TextBox>
            <small class="error">Postcode is required.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### The cs file for the same is.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateContinentsDropDownList();


        }
        lblCheckEmail.Visible = false;
    }



    private void PopulateContinentsDropDownList()
    {
        DataSet ds = Data.spGetCountries();
        ddlCountry.DataSource = ds;
        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Country_Id";
        ddlCountry.DataBind();

        ListItem liCountry = new ListItem("Select Country");
        ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, liCountry);

        ListItem liState = new ListItem("Select State");
        ddlState.Items.Insert(0, liState);

        ListItem liCity = new ListItem("Select City");
        ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, liCity);

        ListItem liCountryCode = new ListItem("Country Code");
        ddlCountrycode.Items.Insert(0, liCountryCode);

        ddlState.Enabled = false;
        ddlCity.Enabled = false;
    }

    protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCountry.SelectedValue == "")
        {
            ddlState.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlCity.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlState.Enabled = false;
            ddlCity.Enabled = false;
            ddlCountrycode.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlCountrycode.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlState.Enabled = true;

            DataSet ds = Data.spGetStateByCountryId(Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue));
            ddlState.DataSource = ds;
            ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "State_Id";
            ddlState.DataBind();

            DataSet ds1 = Data.spGetCountrycode(Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue));
            ddlCountrycode.DataSource = ds1;
            ddlCountrycode.DataTextField = "CountryCode";
            ddlCountrycode.DataValueField = "Country_Id";
            ddlCountrycode.DataBind();

            //ddlCity.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //ddlCity.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlState.SelectedValue == "")
        {
            ddlCity.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlCity.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlCity.Enabled = true;

            DataSet ds = Data.spGetCityByStateId(Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue));
            ddlCity.DataSource = ds;
            ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
            ddlCity.DataValueField = "City_Id";
            ddlCity.DataBind();


        }
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = Data.spCheckEmail(txtEmail.Text);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email_Id"].ToString() == txtEmail.Text)
            {
                lblCheckEmail.Visible = true;
                lblCheckEmail.Text = "Email id already exists , please enter another email id.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblCheckEmail.Text = "";
                lblCheckEmail.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            Data objpro = new Data();
            string a = ddlYear.SelectedValue;
            string b = ddlMonth.SelectedValue;
            string c = ddlDate.SelectedValue;
            string DateofBirth = ddlDate.SelectedValue + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "/" + ddlYear.SelectedValue;
            objpro.DOB = DateofBirth;
            objpro.Email_Id = txtEmail.Text;
            objpro.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            objpro.Acc_Currency = ddlCurrency.SelectedValue;
            objpro.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            objpro.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            objpro.Gender = ddlGender.SelectedValue;
            objpro.Address1 = txtAddress1.Text;
            objpro.Address2 = txtAddress2.Text;
            objpro.Country = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
            objpro.Region_State = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text;
            objpro.City = ddlCity.SelectedItem.Text;
            objpro.PostalCode = txtPostalCode.Text;
            objpro.Phone_Extension = ddlCountrycode.SelectedValue;
            objpro.PhoneNo = txtPhoneno.Text;


            if (Request.QueryString["Account_Id"] != null)
            {
                ID = Request.QueryString["Account_Id"];
            }
            else
            {
                ID = "0";
            }

            objpro.Account_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
            int k = Data.CustomerInsert(objpro);

            Random randno = new Random();
            int cc = randno.Next(000000, 999999);
            string Uniqueid = "U" + cc;

            if (k != -1)
            {

                Data.spStoreUniqueId(k, Uniqueid);
            }

            Session["UniqueId"] = Uniqueid;
            Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data Saved Successfully');window.location='JoininForm.aspx';", true);
            Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
        }
    }



    protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = Data.spCheckEmail(txtEmail.Text);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email_Id"].ToString() == txtEmail.Text)
            {
                lblCheckEmail.Visible = true;
                lblCheckEmail.Text = "Email id already exists , please enter another email id.";
            }

        }

    }
```

also attaching the image for same.
[Image containing the screen shot of country city and state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGrTy.png)

Thanking You guys for support

Comment: @navnit ..thank you Navnit but i tried applying triggers also.  <Triggers>
                                                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" />
                                                            </Triggers> this i have entered in state dropdownlist update panel..is this the right way

Comment: you can achieve this thing two more ways 1. either you take only one update panel and put every control in that update panel 2. set update panel autoupdate to mannually and update it from code behind . all the way are appropriate including my answer. there is nothing wrong with trigger if you use it effectively

Answer (score 0):

try below code. replace your update panel with below update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
            <div id="countrySubdivisionDiv" class="input-single">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                <small class="error">Region/State/Province is required.
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </ContentTemplate> 
    <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="fdf" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"   maxlength="50">  </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>  
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlState" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>                                                        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I tried doing both the methods but some how ,for some reason City dropdown is not getting updated

Comment: tried doing that but i saw a thing that when i am using update panel the selected index of state debugger is not active due to some reason and then i removed update panel and all is working good